# Error on migrating website : Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL

Tags: php, database, mariadb, lamp, joomla1.5

As a young developer, my first task is to migrate a website on another server. I was thinking it will take me less than 2 days but no. 
The website was made with *PHP 5.6* with the *CMS Joomla! 1.5*. I've migrate the sources, but when I try the page, I got the message:

> Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL

I've tried multiples manipulations:

- I have installed *Plesk Onyx* for do the migration, but same message
- I have tried with *Plesk 12.5*, but same,
- I have tried by copiing sources manually on the serv, it didn't work too
- I have check my *LAMP* server, the php test is okey, the *mysql* (*MariaDB*) too, and *Apache2* test is okey.
- I have already edit the *configuration.php* file, but it's the same problem.
- I have tested on another OS for my server (last one was *Debian*), now I have installed *centos 7*, but I don't change anything.

Don't know what's wrong with my migration, if somebody have and idea, I'm listening

Comment: Well currently the only help you're gonna get here is speculation at best. As you can see you're getting a MySQL error, so you need to check your database, the connection to it from the server and finally the CMS configuration (Joomla) in order for it to connect to your database. If everything there is working as expected, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the connection to my databse is correct. When i connect myself with mysql -u root -p, and whe ni type the password i have no problems, how can i check it differently?

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully with more details we can help you more, but as of the current info, I can't help you more. I hope that you can solve the issue.

Comment: I'll try to have more details but it's hard, because i have nothing on the logs files. I sure the configuraton file is correct, i copy paste the password, the user (root) the db name and the host. And i'm sure mysql work on my server

Comment: Try and test thoroughly every part multiple times, maybe you'll find a small error somewhere that stops the whole flow.Try to connect another way to the database or try to connect the project with another db, just to check if it can connect.

Comment: I have a new information, my website is composed by the repositories httpdocs (the content) error_doc (a list of errors) and log. The error message appears only when i go to httpdocs

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message Joomla gave you. The details you've set for accessing the database are wrong.

Did you create a MySQL database for your new site? Did you import the database from the old site to the new server?

Comment: Yes, i have create a new database on the new server, with the save of the old one (I've extract the save with Plesk). I also use same parameters (exepted the password)

Comment: There's not really anything else it can be. Joomla can't connect to the database, so either the db type, the db host, the db username, or the db password are wrong.

Comment: I've checked 100 times the configuration.php file, the db type is mysql, the host is localhost, the user is root, and i'm sure the password is correct to, I've check with others peoples for being sure. The prefix is right too